# Projectiles only spawn when player is still

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an odd problem I can't seem to solve. I have some code that spawns bullets and fires them in the direction the player is facing. It all works fine while the player is still and not moving but as soon as I set the player in motion the code ceases to be called. I've put the spawn code and movement code below. Anyone able to shed some light on this for me?

*Spawn Code*

```
var clone:GameObject;

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
{
    Debug.Log("Fire");
    clone = Instantiate(projectile, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
}
```

*Bullet Movement Code*

```
function Start ()
{
    speed = 10;
    startTime = Time.time;
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    bulletRot = player.rigidbody.rotation;
}

function Update ()
{
    //Debug.Log("Start: " + startTime + "      Live: " + liveTime);
    rigidbody.rotation = bulletRot;
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    liveTime = Time.time - startTime;
    if(liveTime > maxLive)
    {
        DestroyBullet(gameObject);
    }
}
```

*Player Movement Code*

```
function Update ()
{
    Borders();

    var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);

    var horizontal : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * -speed;
    var depth : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;

    horizontal *= Time.deltaTime;
    depth *= Time.deltaTime;
    //yVel *= Time.deltaTime;

    transform.position.z += horizontal;
    transform.position.x += depth;

    //Debug.Log("Y Velocity: " + yVel);
    //Debug.Log("Jumping: " + isJumping);

    //Jump control
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isJumping == false)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Space Pressed");
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if(isJumping)
    {
        updates++;

        if(updates < 10)
        {
            yVel += baseVel;
        }

        else if(updates > 10)
        {
            yVel -= gravity;
        }

        transform.position.y += yVel;

        if(transform.position.y < groundPos + playerHeight)
        {
            transform.position.y = groundPos + playerHeight;
            yVel = 0;
            isJumping = false;
            updates = 0;
        }
    }

    if(transform.position.x >= 29.3)
    {
        transform.position.x = 29.3;
    }

    else if(transform.position.x <= 26.3)
    {
        transform.position.x = 26.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the Borders function do? Also, where in relation to your character is bulletSpawn? Is it any kind of motion (falling, running, jumping) that stops the spawning? There isn't much in the code you posted that could interfere with spawning so my guess is that the problem is elsewhere.